# How to select a dynamic number of rows with mysql

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table, myTable, like this:

```
ID1   Value    ID2
1     6.5064   3
2     7.9000   3
3     9.9390   3
4     8.6585   3
```

What I'm trying to do is SELECT each of those Value's for a given ID2.  However, the number of rows returned for Value can change.  So, if ID2 = 2, only 1 row might get returned.  If drID = 4, 3 rows might get returned.
The part of my query that is trying to handle this is nested, so when I run it I get a "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.  Any idea how I can select a variable number of rows in this way?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: here is what I have so far, and the commented out portion is what I expected to select those values for me, but it throws the above mentioned error:

```
SELECT drDateTime AS Date,
(SELECT fncName FROM functionlist 
WHERE datarecord.fncID = functionlist.fncID) AS FunctionName,

(SELECT alText FROM alarmlevellist
WHERE datarecord.alID = alarmlevellist.alID) AS AlarmDescription

#(SELECT rdValue FROM rawdata
#WHERE datarecord.drID = rawdata.drID)

FROM datarecord
WHERE alID IS NOT NULL AND drSumFlag = 1;
```

Comment: What is the query you are using?

Comment: It really depends on how the outer query interacts with the nested subquery. Can you post the whole query?

Comment: don't use `WHERE COL = (SUBQUERY)` but `WHERE COL IN (SUBQUERY)` instead.

Comment: Post the full query, it will be alot easer to awnser your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show your query.

One common place this problem occurs is in `where` (or `having`) clauses.  A solution to this problem is to use `in` rather than `=`, if the subquery is in the `where` clause.  If you have something like:

```
where id = (select id2 . . .)
```

Then change it to:

```
where id in (select id2 . . .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a join instead of a subquery. I would probably use a join for all tables but that is up to you.

```
SELECT drDateTime AS Date,
(SELECT fncName FROM functionlist WHERE datarecord.fncID = functionlist.fncID) AS FunctionName,
(SELECT alText FROM alarmlevellist WHERE datarecord.alID = alarmlevellist.alID) AS AlarmDescription,
rawData.drID
FROM datarecord
INNER JOIN rawdata
ON datarecord.drID = rawdata.drID)
WHERE alID IS NOT NULL AND drSumFlag = 1;
```